# I can't get what keys are the problem(Key error:260)

Tags: python, keyerror

```
        if epoch % sample_interval == 0:
          print ("%d [D loss: %f, acc.: %.2f%%] [G loss: %f]" % (epoch, d_loss[0], 100*d_loss[1], g_loss))
          self.disc_loss.append(d_loss[0])
          self.gen_loss.append(g_loss)
    
    self.generate(notes)
    self.plot_loss()
    
def generate(self, input_notes):
    # Get pitch names and store in a dictionary
    notes = input_notes
    pitchnames = sorted(set(item for item in notes))
    int_to_note = dict((number, note) for number, note in enumerate(pitchnames))
    
    # Use random noise to generate sequences
    noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, (1, self.latent_dim))
    predictions = self.generator.predict(noise)
    
    pred_notes = [x*242+242 for x in predictions[0]]
    pred_notes = [int_to_note[int(x)] for x in pred_notes]
    
    create_midi(pred_notes, 'gan_final')
    
def plot_loss(self):
    plt.plot(self.disc_loss, c='red')
    plt.plot(self.gen_loss, c='blue')
    plt.title("GAN Loss per Epoch")
    plt.legend(['Discriminator', 'Generator'])
    plt.xlabel('Epoch')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.savefig('GAN_Loss_per_Epoch_final.png', transparent=True)
    plt.close()
```

Above is the code that must be the problem.

The error message is

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-0f77230c1879> in <module>()
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      2   gan = GAN(rows=100)
----> 3   gan.train(epochs=5000, batch_size=32, sample_interval=1)

2 frames
<ipython-input-7-a73ad9b8be55> in train(self, epochs, batch_size, sample_interval)
    113               self.gen_loss.append(g_loss)
    114 
--> 115         self.generate(notes)
    116         self.plot_loss()
    117 

<ipython-input-7-a73ad9b8be55> in generate(self, input_notes)
    127 
    128         pred_notes = [x*242+242 for x in predictions[0]]
--> 129         pred_notes = [int_to_note[int(x)] for x in pred_notes]
    130 
    131         create_midi(pred_notes, 'gan_final')

<ipython-input-7-a73ad9b8be55> in <listcomp>(.0)
    127 
    128         pred_notes = [x*242+242 for x in predictions[0]]
--> 129         pred_notes = [int_to_note[int(x)] for x in pred_notes]
    130 
    131         create_midi(pred_notes, 'gan_final')

KeyError: 260
```

I can't get what key is the problem... And what does 260 means?

Plus there was no problem during learning, Generating after the learning was ther problem.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16fHVeUDtIFbnEE48C3CGaZEFcsKVpnY0?hl=ko#scrollTo=YaR_hiOGXzm8

If the whole code is necessary

Comment: The KeyError is obvious. You're trying to access a key in a dictionary which doesn't exist. Look where you define `int_to_note`. What is `len(pitchnames)`? If that is correct, then you have an invalid number is `pred_notes`, in this case the number 260. Something has to give; either `pitchnames` must be long enough to include the number 260, or 260 should never be in `pred_notes`, or you're just supposed to return a default value for keys that don't exist, i.e., `int_to_note.get(int(x), default_value)`.

Comment: 260 is the key of your dictionary you are trying to access and that does not exists. This is why the error is raised.

Comment: @dkswodyd please paste all your code and be sure the indent is correct. We should be able to see what is the class owning the methods `generate`, `plot_loss`, etc.